# Keep observations that appear consecutively 5 years before and after the event

Tags: loops, stata, panel

I have an unbalanced panel dataset in Stata and am conducting an event study. The variable `window` counts years before or after the event happens for each firm. I want to keep only those firms that are observed for the window [-5, 5]. In the example dataset below, that means that `id=1` should be kept in the data and `id=2` should be dropped because two years before the event the id was not observed, that is window = -2 is absent.

How to write a loop that keeps units that are observed only for -5 to 5 consecutive years before and after the event, so to make the data balanced in Stata?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtp3v.png)

Comment: Please include a data example directly in your question, not indirectly as an image. See the tag wiki for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criterion is that observations are present for all the years in each  window -5(1)5,  which is that the result of

```
  egen count = total(inrange(window, -5, 5)), by(id)
```

is always 11, so that you perhaps proceed with

```
  keep if count == 11 
  keep if inrange(window, -5, 5)
```

No loops needed.